# Get container type from expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Is it possible to get the `Type` for `employee` in this example?

`@Html.MediaFor(x => employee.ProfileImage)`?

The signature for `MediaFor` is

`MediaFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)`

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an expression here in the first place?

Comment: Not really, I guess I could just remove the `Expression` and just use go with the `Func` but does that really change anything?

Comment: What I'm getting at is what is it that `MediaFor` does exactly. Why does it need to know the type?

Comment: `MediaFor` renders an `img` tag and to be able to render that correctly I need the `Type` on which the property `ProfileImage` is declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one of the benefits of having an `Expression<>` is that you can inspect it's parts. Your accessor is a `MemberExpression`, and it's `Expression` property will be the `Expression` that the member is accessed on. So retrieve the `Type` of that:

Example:

```
public static Type GetRootType<T1,T2>(Expression<Func<T1,T2>> expr)
{
    MemberExpression mex = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
    return mex.Expression.Type;     
}
```

Of course, this can be extended to support varying types of expressions, the example will only work for a simple `MemberExpression`. Error checking omitted for brevity.